# cocoa - How to programmatically retrieve the amount of memory your application is using?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory-management

I would like to know how much memory my application is using. How would I be able to retrieve this programmatically? Is there an easy Cocoa way to do this, or would I have to go all the way down to C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working snippet:

```
struct task_basic_info info;
mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                               TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                               (task_info_t)&info,
                               &size);
if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know the original source anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)getMemoryUsedInMegaBytes
{
    NSInteger memoryInBytes = [self getMemoryUsedInBytes];

    return memoryInBytes/1048576;
}

- (NSInteger)getMemoryUsedInBytes
{
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) 
    {
        return info.resident_size;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```